# Training convolutional nets on multi-channel image data sets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am trying to implement a convolutional neural network from scratch and I am not able to figure out how to perform  (vectorized)operations on multi-channel images like rgb, which have 3 dimensions. On following the articles and tutorials such as [this CS231n tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)  , it's pretty clear to implement a network for a single input as the input layer will be a 3d matrix but there are always multiple data points in a dataset. so, I cannot figure out how to implement these networks for vectorized operation on entire datsets.

I have implemented a network which takes a 3d matrix as input but now I have realized that It will not work on entire dataset but I will have to propagate one input at a time.I don't really know whether conv nets are vectorized over entire dataset or not .But if they are, how can I vectorize my convolutional network for multi-channel images ?

Comment: Are you using some library for this? In general channels is something that CNNs handle very easily.

Comment: @JonasAdler I am using armadillo library for c++ to handle linear algebra. Specifically, I use matrix and cube data structures for 2D and 3D matrices respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question right, you're basically asking how to do convolutional layer for a mini-batch, which will be a 4-D tensor.

To put it simply, you want to treat each input in a batch independently and apply convolution to each one. It's fairly straightforward to code without vectorization using a loop.

A vectorization implementation is often based on [im2col technique](https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/07/16/convnet-conv-layer/), which basically transforms the 4-D input tensor into a giant matrix and performs a matrix multiplication. Here's an implementation of a forward pass using `numpy.lib.stride_tricks` in python:

```
import numpy as np

def conv_forward(x, w, b, stride, pad):
  N, C, H, W = x.shape
  F, _, HH, WW = w.shape

  # Check dimensions
  assert (W + 2 * pad - WW) % stride == 0, 'width does not work'
  assert (H + 2 * pad - HH) % stride == 0, 'height does not work'

  # Pad the input
  p = pad
  x_padded = np.pad(x, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (p, p), (p, p)), mode='constant')

  # Figure out output dimensions
  H += 2 * pad
  W += 2 * pad
  out_h = (H - HH) / stride + 1
  out_w = (W - WW) / stride + 1

  # Perform an im2col operation by picking clever strides
  shape = (C, HH, WW, N, out_h, out_w)
  strides = (H * W, W, 1, C * H * W, stride * W, stride)
  strides = x.itemsize * np.array(strides)
  x_stride = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x_padded,
                                             shape=shape, strides=strides)
  x_cols = np.ascontiguousarray(x_stride)
  x_cols.shape = (C * HH * WW, N * out_h * out_w)

  # Now all our convolutions are a big matrix multiply
  res = w.reshape(F, -1).dot(x_cols) + b.reshape(-1, 1)

  # Reshape the output
  res.shape = (F, N, out_h, out_w)
  out = res.transpose(1, 0, 2, 3)
  out = np.ascontiguousarray(out)
  return out
```

Note that it uses some non-trivial features of linear algebra library, which are implemented in `numpy`, but may be not in your library.

BTW, you generally don't want to push the entire data set as one batch - split it into several batches.

Comment: Is there any way to vectorize the backward pass( deconvolution ) ?